# flash menu with submenu and gradient colors?

Tags: flashmenu

I'm new to flash, and would like to create a flash menu with submenus. Also, the background colors for the menu elements need to be gradient images as well.

Any suggestions where I could find some tutorials?

am lookin for something similar to 
[this](http://www.flash-extensions.net/menus/total-flash-menu/total_menu_free1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [Adobe Flex](http://flex.org) a try.  It is basically Flash for application developers and (assuming you are coming from an application development background) you may find it easier to build a Flash menu in.

However it does require your users to have Flash 9 or higher and on the earliest versions of the Flash 9 player the SWF file can be quite large (later versions have better support for caching the Flex framework).